# close an open tab in browser from C#

Tags: c#, google-chrome, tabs

is there any way to close a tab on CHROME, Firefox and IE from C#?  I believe that I can accomplish this via JavaScript but I do not know how to call a JS from my C# application.  By way of background, my app opens a browser, interacts with the caller then I need to close the open tab.

Comment: Is this a web application or a desktop application?

Comment: In a web application you can't do it i guess

Answer (score 0):

You probably won't be too successful trying to close a specific tab in the opened browser. You could try to call Process.CloseMainWindow on the launched process, but this may get tricky and potentially close other tabs.

You may want to consider creating a new window (WPF) or form (WinForms) in your app and use the embedded browser control.

Answer (score -2):

If the page you're opening is an asp.net you that you can code... In the method which you want to close the tab, use:

```
Response.Write("<script type=\"text/javascript\">window.close();</script>");
```

Otherwise, I can't think of a way either.